# Function Templates Compiler Error

Tags: c++

I made a very simple program to understand Function Templates with multiple Parameters but I keep on getting this error message from the compiler. I've looked over the program a bunch of times but I cant seem to understand where the problem is coming from. I would really appreciate any insight.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class FIRST, class SECOND>
FIRST smaller(FIRST a, SECOND b)
{
      return (a<b?a:b);
}

int main()
{

    int x = 21;
    double y = 12.2; 
    cout << smaller(x,y) << endl;

}
```

Compiler error message:

- In function `FIRST smaller(FIRST, SECOND) [with FIRST = int, SECOND = double]':
- instantiated from here
- [Warning] converting to 'int' from 'double'

Comment: The compiler giving a.clear diagnostic.

Comment: BTW: There's already `std::min()` available, doing this right ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ std::min expects arguments of same type

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it's a warning rather than an error.

What it's telling you is that you are implicitly converting a `double` to `int`. This would result in loss of precision.

The conversion happens because the return type is the same type as the first argument, which in your example is `int`.

Comment: Solution -> `std::common_type` or `-> decltype(a < b? a: b)`

Answer (score 0):

That to escape the warning (thogh it can be considered by the compiler as an error if you will switch on a corresponding compiler option "consider warnings as errors") saying about the loss of precision while converting from double to int you could write the function the following way

```
template <class FIRST, class SECOND>
auto smaller(FIRST a, SECOND b) ->typename std::common_type<FIRST, SECOND>::type
{
      return ( a < b ? a : b );
}
```

That to do this you have to include header `<type_traits>`